# How to write the Jquery condition for - If a variable value is <space>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a validation condition based on a variable name - test. I'm taking the textbox value to a variable- test. If user add  character want to restrict the form submission. Below second OR condition will not suit for me because if user input multiple  it won't work.
Suggestions please...

```js
if(test =="" || test == " "){
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to check if a string *contains* whitespace or *is entirely* whitespace?

Comment: You can trim that variable and then test condition.

Comment: @David both applicable for me.

Comment: if(!test.trim()){} ->for total whitespaces  and if(test.indexOf(' ') != -1){} -> for any whitespace.

Comment: @rrkjonnapalli: worked well for me.

Comment: Thanks you all @all

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are trying to check if user just added white spaces and tries to submit. You can use [**`$.trim`**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/) for that

```js
$("#b").click(function(){
    
    if($.trim($("#t").val()) === ""){
        alert("not valid")
     }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="t"></textarea>

<button id="b">Check</button>
```

Even if there are multiple whitespaces `$.trim` will return you  `""`. So you don't have to worry about taking care for more than one white spaces

Comment: Thanks you all @all